# Processing the fruit of chequers/wild service tree

Tags: foraging, trees, forests

How do I process the fruit of the [wild service tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorbus_torminalis)?

I know the berries need to be subjected to frost before they can be dried and consumed.

- Can I harvest them early and stick them in the freezer for a few hours instead?
- How do I know when they are dried/ripened enough ready for eating?

Comment: If this tree is anything like a sloe bush, freezing the berries to fake a frost often leaves you with a much worse flavour than waiting out, but should be possible. :)

Comment: I make jams and jellies out of wild berries every year but have never dried wild berries of any sort. I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that you can adapt any method that is used for medlar or common medlar (mespilus germanica). 
So freezer should work.

*How do I know when they are dried/ripened enough ready for eating?*

Take some courage - try one. ;)